# Floating eye win / loss condition [spoilers]

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

If a hero is broken out of mind control, they cannot be controlled again. Heroes that are controlled do not attack other heroes, only board the spaceship. Does this mean that if a single hero breaks mind control, the heroes automatically win, with the freed hero just bashing the spaceship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No, a hero breaking free of mind control does not itself make the game unwinnable for the traitor.

The Traitor's win condition for this haunt is exactly as follows:

> #### You Win When ...
>
> ... all of the heroes are either dead or on the spaceship.

Note that if either of these happens to a hero, they are out of the game. Effectively, this means that the traitor wins when all heroes are unable to act. The "can only mind control a hero once" limitation simply means that any hero that breaks free of mind control must be killed for the traitor to win.

Comment: But the traitor has no way to kill heroes, so the only way for them to die would be to enter a room and have it kill them.  IMHO there should be a time limit on destroying the space ship.

Comment: *"... the traitor has no way to kill heroes"* - ***what?!*** This is not correct at all. The Alien can make Might attacks on Heroes.

Comment: Oh, that is what I was missing.